# Redirect all files in folder to a new sub domain using htacess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to use a .htaccess file to redirect all the pages, files and URL permutations within this IP address website, for example:

```
http://123.456.11.222/~account/downloads/customerxyz/oneofmyfiles.zip
http://123.456.11.222/~account/downloads/customer123/example
http://123.456.11.222/~account/downloads/newcustomer/test.jpg
...etc
```

to a new sub-domain like this

```
http://sub.newdomain.com/downloads/customerxyz/oneofmyfiles.zip
http://sub.newdomain.com/downloads/customer123/example
http://sub.newdomain.com/downloads/newcustomer/test.jpg
...etc
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this so all files and URL's in the downloads folder are redirected to the new location?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `/~account/downloads/.htaccess` file with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) http://sub.newdomain.com/downloads/$1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: `301` - Moved Permanently
`302` - Found (HTTP 1.1) / Moved Temporarily (HTTP 1.0).


so I recommend to use `301` because it's better for SEO

Comment: Yes `301` should be used after verifying rule is working fine. `302` is good for testing otherwise `301` is cached aggressively in browsers.